# Private inheritance in C++ with minimum example.

Tags: c++, inheritance

since I don't feel super comfortable with protected, private inheritance in C++ I googled it up and came up with this stackoverflow answer: [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance?answertab=oldest#tab-top) . 
Nice! I thought, let us try this out. So I wrote a small example program to test this and wrote the exptected output as comment.

```
 class Person{
   public: virtual void publicInterface() {}
   protected: virtual void protectedInterface() {}
   private: virtual void privateInterface() {}
    };

    class Professor : public Person  {};
    class Teacher : protected Person { 
    public: void teachPublic(){publicInterface();}
    public: void teachProtected(){protectedInterface();}
    public: void teachPrivate(){privateInterface();}        // not compiling
    };
    class Student : private Person {
    public: void learnPublic(){publicInterface();}
    public: void learnProtected(){protectedInterface();} 
    public: void learnPrivate(){privateInterface();}        // not compiling
    };
    int main()
    {
        Person* p = new Person();       // ok is-a
    Person* pro = new Professor();  // ok    is-a
        Person* t = new Teacher();      // not compiling! No is-a relat.
        Person* s = new Student();      // not compiling! No is-a
        Teacher* t2 = new Teacher();        // ok
        Student* s2 = new Student();    // ok
        pro->publicInterface();     // ok
    t2->publicInterface();      // not compiling
    s2->publicInterface();      // not compiling
    t2->teachPublic();          // ok
    t2->teachProtected();           // ok
    t2->teachPrivate();         // not compiling
    s2->learnPublic();          // ok
    s2->learnProtected();       // not compiling   <-- compiles, but why?
    s2->learnPrivate();         // not compiling
    }
```

Running this it does mostly exactly what I would expect. However, the second last line seem to compile - which is kind of not exptected from the described behaviour of private inheritance.

Has someone an idea why this is compiling?

Comment: This is not java, you don't need `public:` on the each line.

Comment: It compiles because `learnProtected` is a public member function of `Student`, it's irrevelant what it does or doesn't call.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Is correct. Remember that typically (with non-inliine functions) the compiler cannot access the function implementation at all at the point of call. What it can see is the *declaration* in the class declaration.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, right that is correct. However, than the call inside learn protected should not compile   `public: void learnProtected(){protectedInterface();}`

Comment: Type of inheritance doesn't matter inside the derived class. It only matters outside.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, you mean ".. and can call .. " , right? Hmm, but still something does not make sense for me yet. Student inherits only privately from Person so it shouldn't be allowed to call a protected function, right?

Comment: .. or phrased differently, what is than the difference between private and protected inheritance?

Comment: Private inheritance: The class itself knows what it inherits from and can use all non-private functions from the base, but outside code doesn't know that the class inherits from the base. Protected inheritanace: Same, but classes derived from this class know that it's derived from the base.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat "_outside code doesn't know that the class inherits from the base_" Wrong! Outside code (meaning any code that isn't member or friend) just cannot use a derived to base **conversion**.

Comment: @curiousguy Huh. Maybe I'm missing something, but can you provide an example demonstrating that it's wrong?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You cannot refer in valid code to base class data members  member to modify them or to function to call them; but name lookup still sees these members and thus they **hide** global declarations with the same name. They are *not* invisible.

Comment: The use of private inheritance can also be observed by well formed code that doesn't have access. [See f.ex.](https://onlinegdb.com/r1cnBB2bX) produces "(is_base_of<A,Der>::value) 1                                                                                                                         
(is_base_of<A,Der_priv>::value) 1" which means that private inheritance is a property measurable by type traits.

Comment: @curiousguy That's some good points, thanks.

Comment: See also [that multiple inheritance](https://onlinegdb.com/B1EIDS2-m) (note that this is *non* virtual inheritance): in `Most_der` there are two base class subobjects `A` but only one is accessible; direct derived to base conversion from `Most_der` to `A` is non-the-less ambiguous, because access checking isn't done before the conversion resolution: a conversion must be to only one base subobject (OTOH, in case of virtual inheritance, there is one subobject of a type, with many paths).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat There is also the fact that a virtual function in a base class can be overridden without referring to its declaration, so without access control. So private virtual functions can be overridden, or virtual functions in private base classes.

Answer (score 0):

The method `learnProtected` is public. Therefore it is callable "from outside" (i.e. via `s2`).

The method `protectedInterface` is protected, which means it is only accessible by the members and friends of `Person` or by the members of any class derived from `Person`. `Student` class is derived from `Person` and therefore `learnProtected` can call `protectedInterface`.

The fact that it privately inherits from `Person` does only affect the external visibility of the Base class and members. `Student` itself can access any public or protected member of `Person` no matter which inheritance (private, protected, public) is used.

Answer (score 0):

yes, thank you HolyBlackCat!

I have now an example that explains for me the behaviour of private inheritance:

```
    class Person{
    public: virtual void publicInterface() {}
    protected: virtual void protectedInterface() {}
    private: virtual void privateInterface() {}
};
class Professor : public Person  {};
class Teacher : protected Person { 
public: void teachPublic(){publicInterface();}
void teachProtected(){protectedInterface();}    // ok!
    void teachPrivate(){privateInterface();}        // not compiling
};
class Student : private Person {
public: void learnPublic(){publicInterface();}
void learnProtected(){protectedInterface();}    // ok!
void learnPrivate(){privateInterface();}        // not compiling
};
class TA : public Teacher {
public: void correctExercises(){publicInterface();}
};
class Child : public Student {
public: void play(){publicInterface();}  //NOT working, since we priva
};
int main()
{
    Person* p = new Person();       // ok is-a
Person* pro = new Professor();  // ok    is-a
    Person* t = new Teacher();      // not compiling! No is-a relat.
    Person* s = new Student();      // not compiling! No is-a
    Teacher* t2 = new Teacher();        // ok
    Student* s2 = new Student();    // ok
    pro->publicInterface();     // ok
t2->publicInterface();      // not compiling
s2->publicInterface();      // not compiling
t2->teachPublic();          // ok
t2->teachProtected();           // ok
t2->teachPrivate();         // not compiling
s2->learnPublic();          // ok
s2->learnProtected();           // ok! learnProteted is public
s2->learnPrivate();         // not compiling
TA* ta = new TA();          // ok 
Child* c = new Child();     // ok
ta->correctExercises(); // ok
c->play();              // ok however call inside play not ok!
}
```

But I still think this is quite obscure .. no one would really come up with such a design in real world, right?

Answer (score -2):

The function Person::learnProtected() is not visible in the class Student, so when you declare Student::learnProtected(), the compiler understands it as not override declaration.

You could ensure this adding the constrain "override" to Student::learnProtected(), the compiler will show an error when the function is not overriding a parent virtual function:

```
public: void learnProtected() override { protectedInterface(); }
```

This causes the compiler error:

> C3668 'Student::learnProtected': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods    ConsoleApplication3

Comment: the OP's example use no override at all.